# C# lock not working when log csv to appendblob

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await, azure-blob-storage, linqtocsv

I have an application where in i log to **azure appendblob** as csv. I am using LinqToCsv->CsvContext to write as csv.

Each time i write the log, i check if the appendblob has got any length, if it is zero then i write the header to the csv.
Every thing is working fine until i tested in multi threaded manner. Because of this the header is not written once instead written many time in the csv.

I have used **lock** statement to block multiple thread to access the block of statement, but it is not working as expected.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task WriteToAudit(AuditData auditData)
{
    _auditBlobName = Utilities.GetAuditAppendBlobName(auditData.Container);

    var appendBlob = await GetAppendBlobReferenceAsync();

    var list = new List<AuditData> { auditData };

    var auditDataBytes = CloudAppendBlobHelper.WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory(list, appendBlob);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(auditDataBytes))
    {
        await appendBlob.AppendBlockAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public static class CloudAppendBlobHelper
{
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

    public static byte[] WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory(IEnumerable<AuditData> records, CloudAppendBlob appendBlob)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            appendBlob.FetchAttributes();

            var outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',',
                EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true,
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = appendBlob.Properties.Length <= 0
            };

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    var context = new CsvContext();
                    context.Write(records, streamWriter, outputFileDescription);
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of locking *and* doing multithreading?

Comment: Requirement is the WriteToAudit method will be called inside an iteration loop.

Comment: Just to clarify: is it the point to write the header only once?

Comment: Comment: `CloudAppendBlobHelper.WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory()` should be pure, no locks needed.

Comment: Btw, if you write to `MemoryStream`, you can just `Write()` without async/await.

Comment: C# 4.0 does not have async-await.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling 'Fetch Attributes' inside a lock, but you are not then calling the AppendBlock API inside the lock as well.  This introduces a race condition, where the following order of operations is possible:

- Thread 1 enters WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory, and then exits.  The header is included, because the length of the blob is 0.
- Thread 2 enters WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory, and then exits.  The header is included, because the length of the blob is (still) 0.
- Thread 1 calls AppendBlock and writes the header.
- Thread 2 calls AppendBlock and writes the header.

One solution is to put the AppendBlock call inside the lock as well.

If you want to keep the parallelism, another solution is to use an [AccessCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.accesscondition.aspx).  When you are writing the header, you could use an "ifAppendPositionEqual" condition, or an "ifMaxSizeLessThanOrEqual" condition, for example.  These will cause the write operation to fail on the service if the condition is not met.  You would then need to catch the failure, and redo the append operation without the header.  If you do this, I think you should be able to remove the lock completely.

Note that you'll need to know at the time of the AppendBlock call whether or not you're writing the header.

Comment: Thank you. Would appreciate if you could direct me to an example as I am new to Azure.

Comment: Based on this https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock seems we can't use await inside lock